# Windows server 2012 Domain Controller two NICs with different network profiles

Tags: windows

I have a Windows server 2012 Domain Controller with two NICs, one in an internal network and another on an external network. How can I force the second NIC to be in a public profile?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfJka.png]

Comment: As no one else already said it, I'll step forward: WTH? your DC connected to an external network?! What about a proper firewall and DMZ?

Answer (score 2):

Look in here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

Change the `Category` key to the appropriate setting.

```
Public = 0
Home = 1
Work = 2
```

Powershell method (probably more reliable):

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex # -NetworkCategory Public
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not do what I want. I want one NIC on the aop.local domain and the second NIC as public.

Comment: You want one NIC to use a public profile and one to use the domain profile ... that's exactly how you do it ... There's a GUID per NIC in the Profiles hive, and the Category Key sets the profile type. Pick the GUID that corresponds with your NIC, flip the bit, done. If that's not what you want to do, please update your question.

Comment: I wish you were right... my problem would be solved, but it does not work and besides if I restart the server it resets to 2. In the Profiles hive I do have 2 entries, one for ProfileName aop.local and another for ProfileName network. Thanks !

Comment: I added a powershell method in my answer. I wonder if this is related to the DNS settings on your adapters ... can you try adding your internal DNS to eth1? There's some method of autodetect that must be assigning private profiles to your adapters based on "location" ...